# What happens to matter and antimatter in quantum fluctuations if a photon interacts with it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What happens to matter and antimatter in quantum fluctuations if a photon interacts with it? If the photon had the right frequency, could the energy of the photon disrupt the process of the fluctuation? If the mass of the photon was added to either the matter or antimatter, would it gain energy, then interact with the opposite particle and the remaining energy would resolve as a photon? Almost as if nothing happened?

Comment: What do you mean by "in quantum fluctuations"? We can do scattering experiments involving photons and matter and antimatter, but the "in quantum fluctuations" language suggests that you might have been led astray (as many have) by some pop-sci descriptions of quantum field theory. In quantum electrodynamics, a photon propagating through the vacuum propagates as a free photon, without encountering anything. There are "vacuum fluctuations" in the sense that strictly-localized particle-detectors are necessarily noisy, but pop-sci descriptions often misuse the "fluctuation" language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum fluctuations, more normally described as vacuum fluctuations, are described by Feynman diagrams like this.

[image: vacuum fluctuation]

This appears to show the spontaneous creation and annihilation of a particle-antiparticle pair in the vacuum. Such diagrams have gained enormous importance in bad science and in pop science, and have even been used to miscalculate the [vacuum catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem). The vacuum is said to be full of such processes. The calculation of a vacuum fluctuation diagram is seriously divergent, but because they do not, by definition, interact with matter in the universe, they are not part of the universe and should not be calculated.

The moment a photon "interacts with a vacuum fluctuation", it is no longer a vacuum fluctuation. We have a different process.

We can have diagrams like

[image]

Again the formal calculation is divergent, but there are good arguments to show that this does not actually alter the photon propagator.

Comment: Thank you that answers my question very well.